# Can't unselect ListView item when deleting it

Tags: java, android, listview

Trudging my way through my introduction to Java and Android on a simple app and have run into an issue with ListView item selection.  For one of my activities, I have a layout with two buttons, one of which is a "Delete" button, and a ListView of "passages" which are essentially timestamps for when a device has passed a sensor.

I have implemented the ability to click on an item to select it, which then enables the "Delete" button.  A click of the "Delete" button removes the "passage" but I still end up with a selected item, which I don't want.

To implement selection, I added the following property to the ListView:

```
    android:id="@+id/passagesListView"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="#666666"
```

Selection is supported in OnCreate via a an OnItemClickListener:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_passages);
        passagesViewAdapter = new PassagesViewAdapter(this, R.layout.passages_row_layout, passages);

        final ListView passagesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.passagesListView);
        assert passagesListView != null;

        final Button deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        deleteButton.setEnabled(false);

        buildPassageList();
        passagesListView.setAdapter(passagesViewAdapter);

        passagesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewPassagesActivity.this, "position is " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                view.setSelected(true);
                passagesViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                selectedItemPos = position;
                deleteButton.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });
    }
```

This part works.  However, there is some issue with deletion.  As you can see in the comments, I have tried several methods that I found on StackOverflow that seemed to apply but, although I am able to delete the correct item from the list, I am still ending up with a selected item after the call to delete().

```
    public void delete (View view)
    {
        final Button deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        ListView passagesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.passagesListView);

        if(selectedItemPos != -1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(ViewPassagesActivity.this, "remove " + selectedItemPos,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // This did not work, which is strange since it worked similarly for selection when clicked
//            View itemView = passagesListView.getChildAt(selectedItemPos);
            View itemView = passagesViewAdapter.getView(selectedItemPos, null, passagesListView);
            itemView.setSelected(false);

            // This was also recommended in various posts on StackOverflow.
            // Not clear whether clearChoices applies only to checkBoxes?
//            passagesListView.clearChoices();
//            passagesListView.requestLayout();

            passages.remove(selectedItemPos);
            deleteButton.setEnabled(false);
            selectedItemPos = -1;

            passagesViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }}
}
```

I also ran into some issues trying to track which item is selected via setSelected() and getSelectedItemPosition() and punted by just tracking the index myself.  So, as I am new to this, I'm sure there is something I am not understanding about Views or maybe something else such as a misunderstanding of how selection works?

How can I clear the selection?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a point of clarification here since I provided a lot of background.  The TLDR here is that I want to select and delete a ListView item with no items selected after deletion.

Comment: Try add this after your notifyDataSetChanged(), "passagesListView.invalidateViews();".

Comment: No change with that call.  The highlight remains at the position after the item is deleted.

Comment: Try replace "itemView.setSelected(false)" with this, passagesListView.setItemChecked(selectedItemPos, false);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your PassagesViewAdapter class looks like. Maybe you can try

```
passagesViewAdapter.remove(passages.get(selectedItemPos));
passages.remove(selectedItemPos);
deleteButton.setEnabled(false);
selectedItemPos = -1;

passagesViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: That results in the same behavior.  The item is deleted but the same position remains selected.